# Using mathspec to change digits font in math mode isn't working

Tags: math-mode, libertine, mathspec

I'd like to use the Linux Libertine font with a document, and I'm running into a problem with digits in math mode. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[math]{mathspec}
\setprimaryfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
1 $1$ $\mathrm{1}$ $\text{1}$
\end{document}
```

which, when compiled with XeLaTeX, produces the following (no errors reported):

> [image]

As you can see, `$1$` still gives Computer Modern. But my understanding [from the `mathspec` documentation](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdf) is that `\setprimaryfont` should apply to digits in math mode:

> [image]

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about the documentation, or perhaps I have a problem with my fonts. I'm using TeXstudio 2.6.6 with MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Any help with getting `$1$` to make a Linux Libertine `1` would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply remove the option `math` when loading `mathspec`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setprimaryfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
1 $1$ $\mathrm{1}$ $\text{1}$
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Loading `mathspec` with the `math` option forces `mathspec` to load `fontspec` without the `no-math` option.

And the `fontspec` manual states:

> If you find that `fontspec` is incorrectly changing the maths font when it should be leaving well enough alone, apply the `[no-math]` package option to manually suppress its maths font.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer - in my actual document, I used the `math` option for `mathspec` because I would get an error `Option clash for package fontspec. ...Package[\eu@zf@math]{fontspec}[2008/08/09]` if I didn't, but that's just because I was stupidly including the `fontspec` package separately, when the `mathspec` package already calls it.

Comment: Now that I've removed the unnecessary `\usepackage{fontspec}` and the `math` option from `mathspec`, everything's good.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Glad to help.